# adding calculated column in qountmod data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate buy/sell signals using MFI to test a strategy. it's should actually be pretty simple but R is giving me a hard time.

Here's my code:

```
q <- get(getSymbols('spy',src='yahoo'))
q$mfi <- MFI(q[,2:4],q[,5],5)
sig <- function(row) { 
if (row$mfi < 20) { return (1)} 
else if (row$mfi > 80) { return (-1)} 
else { return (0)}}
q$result<-apply(q,1,sig)
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Error in row$mfi : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

if there are better ways of testing strategies using simple conditions i would appreciate it...

Comment: what do you get when you run `typeof(row)`?

Comment: you should access row with an `[]` [indexing operator](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing). You have not defined `x` in your code.

Comment: Señor O - you are right, it's a mistake - i ment to write q instead of x. Eric, i can't get to the row type because the function fails. q is of type "xts" "zoo".

Comment: @user2000875 I think I have do a big mistake to answer such question where there isn't a reproducible example and you don't supply the expected result. It is The last time that I answer such questions. I downvote the question.

Comment: i fixed the example (q instead of x).

Comment: @user2000875 please test you code before asking ! `q$mfi <- MFI(q[,2:4],q[,5],5)` give error : `Error in runSum(pmf, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs`

Comment: it's working for me. i'm using `R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)` for `i386-w64-mingw32`

Answer (score 1):

here no need to use `apply`, use `ifelse`, it is vectorized

```
mfi <- c(10,15,20,50,70,90,100)
res <- ifelse(mfi < 20, 1, ifelse( mfi < 80,0,-1))

rbind(mfi,res)  ## rbind here just to show you the result and you can compare
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
mfi   10   15   20   50   70   90  100
res    1    1    0    0    0   -1   -1
```

**EDIT** dut to the calrify to the OP

```
q <- getSymbols('XXX')
q$mfi <- ....
q$rsi <- ....
sig <- function(q,...) {
  if('mfi' %in% names(q))
    res <- ifelse(mfi < 20, 1, 
                  ifelse( mfi < 80,0,-1))
  else 
    res <- NULL
  res
}
 sig(q)
[1]  1  1  0  0  0 -1 -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. eventually i want to create a generic function signal() that will except a quantmod data frame (row) with all the relevant indicators and generate buy/sell signals. it can be mfi,rsi etc... this is a simplified example.

Comment: @user2000875 in what I prpose can not ben used in a function? replace mfi here by the correct MFI ( you don't give the correct MFI in your question ) and call the line above you will get your indicator..You will apply the same indicator mfi/rsi etc? I think it s not a good idea to put all this in the same function...

Comment: i'll explain. for a given data frame representing stock q i want to generate buy/sell signals using a generic function `signal()`. the function can use different indicators. the function is generated on the fly - the only constant here is the data set, whats changing is the function generating the signals. the format should be `q<-getSymbols('XXX'); # add relevant indicators. # generate buy sell signals using function signal()`. if i'll do it the way you suggest i'll have to `rbind` each indicator and i'm limiting my self to pretty simple conditions.

Comment: @user2000875 I update my answer to clarify you my option. The fact of using `ifelse` in the place of `apply` and the fact of encapsulate all this in a function are 2  independents questions. Hope it is clear now!

Comment: is it not possible to access columns within a data frame from a function dynamically ? something like `sig<-function(row) { if (any(row$mfi<20,row$rsi<20)) { return(1) }}` ? .Thanks for the trouble i'm just having a hard time accomplishing my goal here... eventually i want to implement complex conditions which probably be a maintenance nightmare if i'll use `ifelse` for all of them... Thanks for the patience

Comment: My ifelse is just a **vectorized** version of your if else ( it is fast). So I will not any extra maintenance effort to your original code.

Comment: got it.so back to the original problem - how can i access `row$mfi`,`row$rsi` from within the function. i'm getting `Error in row$mfi : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`, thanks !

Comment: row is atomic vector.  so you can't use $ to access. you need to use index(row[index of mfi]) or row['mfi']. But this is really bad to do ...

Comment: it doesn't work man. the rows gets multiplied. i'm missing something here. this should be easy as iterating a `foreach` loop .... why is apply no good in this case ?  i'm just trying to generate a calculated column using values from other columns.